# What is the best way to select a paragraph starting with eg [1], [2] or [1.1],[1.2] or (1),(2) or (1.1),(1.2) etc using python?

Tags: python, regex

What is the best way to select a paragraph starting with eg [1], [2] or [1.1],[1.2] or (1),(2) or (1.1),(1.2)  etc and ending when you reach the next bracket number.

I tried using following code but this is only working for [] brackets and single digit number.

```
 positions = [] 
# regex to indicate the values [1] or  [2] or ...
pattern = re.compile("\[\d\]") or re.compile("\(\d\)")
# find positions in the string
prev=0
for match in pattern.finditer(text):
    current = text[match.span()[0]+1:match.span()[1]-1]
    if int(current)-int(prev) ==1:
       positions.append(match.start())
    prev = current

last_item=len(positions)-1
# loop throughpositions and print
# print(positions)
for index, item in enumerate(positions):
    start=item
    if index != last_item:
        print('--------Paragraph--------------')
        # print(text[item:positions[index+1]])
        finalText = text[item:positions[index+1]]
        print(finalText)
   
    else:
        print('--------Paragraph--------------')
        print(text[item:])
```

Comment: If this is working but only for square brackets and single digits, did you try changing to `"[[(]\d+[\])]"`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would suggest something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/IueIWw/1).

```
^[\[\(]\d+.?\d*[\]\)]
```

Summary:

- `^`: start of line
- `[\[\(]`: one of either `[` or `(`
- `\d+`: at least one digit
- `.?`: optional `.`
- `\d*`: 0 or more digits
- `[\]\)]`: one of either `]` or `)`

Comment: If I understand the OP requirement: if you add to your regex a capture group and stop when finalizing [ or ( is reached then the code can be simplified to `text2 = re.findall(r"^([\[\(]\d+.?\d*[\]\)].*)[\[\(]", text)[0]`